# Can one git branch bloat another in the same remote?

Tags: git

I have a git repository with a `master` branch on the `origin` remote. Other devs on the team are pushing their own `dev/feature` branches to the same remote. Eventually these branches will either be discarded, or **squash**-merged into `master` and later deleted.

Now some devs on the team are unfamiliar with git and are likely to bloat the history of their feature branches by adding binary files, etc. Eventually they will send a pull review request, which must be reviewed, and reviewers will enforce that no binaries are added.

In this scenario, I expect the `dev/feature` branches to be bloated (e.g. git might become slow, pulling/cloning them might take a while, etc). The question is whether this will cause any performance issues for people just working with other branches in the same remote that are not bloated.

Comment: Consider using [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) for the binaries to avoid repo bloat while still having binaries in version control.

Comment: If you don't have any branch access contronl mechanism, which Git itself does not have, other devs will get the binary-related Git data too when they clone/pull/fetch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The question is whether this will cause any performance issues for people just working with other branches in the same remote that are not bloated.*

If the bloated branches are pushed, yes, it will impact other's performance, but only for `git fetch` (which includes `git pull`). It will download the whole history and full content of every branch by default. There are various ways around this, like `git clone --single-branch` to get only `master`, but there's a better solution below.

But it should not affect other operations. `git diff`, `git log`, etc... should all be largely unaffected.

Rather than preventing people from putting binaries in version control, or cloning only certain branches, use [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/). This is the best of both worlds. You can put binary files in version control, but the actual content is stored outside the repository to avoid repository bloat.

Comment: git-lfs is a great option, but as I understand we have to set up a set of path glob patterns that will be tracked by git-lfs (e.g. *.png, *.a). My fear is that people will inevitably end up submitting binary files that bypass all patterns we have set.

Comment: @roim With a decent network, it shouldn't be a problem if there's the occasional binary commit. And you can fix it retroactively with the BFG. And since you're squash merging branches any bloated history in that branch will be garbage collected.

Comment: ah, so I think I missed this from the answer: when the feature branches are deleted/garbage collected, the bloat will end. Is that the case? If so, might be worth adding to the answer and I'll sleep well at night even if we don't end up using git-lfs. I love the idea of lfs, but support for it is still somewhat experimental in my environment.

Comment: Yes, once the branch is deleted and goes away from the server, the server side bloat will end. Users must also delete any names *they* have (such as remote-tracking branch names) that are holding those commits in *their own* repositories to get their space back, though. They can do that automatically by running `git fetch --prune` ("prune" = "if `foo` is gone on `origin`, remove my `origin/foo` now", which arguably should be the default). It might also be wise to provide a server side pre-receive or update hook that rejects huge files by default, though.

Comment: @roim That's only because you're squash merging, and don't recommend squash merging for exactly that reason: it loses important history. Torek's suggestion of a server side hook that rejects large files unless they're under git-lfs seems the best solution.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of storing 10 iterations of a code review in history. Even for simple code reviews I'd rather just have the full change in 1 record. In our dev cycle feature branches won't generally last longer than a week, so squashing seems the way to go for me.

Comment: @roim Squash merges delete important information that someone months or years down the line can use to figure out why the code was written that way. The more granular the better. If you smash it all together into 500 lines of change, it's hard to know what commit comment refers to what change. Artifacts of code review, like small fixes, can be squashed. Preserve what is useful for future devs trying to puzzle out the code. If you never use it, then it just sits there and doesn't bother anybody. But if you need it and it's not there, there's no recovering that vital information.

Comment: @Schwern we can already use our code review tools (integrated with pull requests) to see why code was written in a given way. That will include not only the incorrect/unreviewed code, but also all comments written by the writer AND the reviewers. That seems a much better source of info for answering the "why" question. Then the "how" question can be answered by just looking at a clean history that shows the effective code changes that were pulled to master. Without a code review tool I'd be with you. Just my 2 cents..